# Initialization goal raised in swi prolog

Tags: swi-prolog

I'm new to swi-prolog. I installed swi-prolog and, at first, it works fine. I am then receiving this error:

> ERROR: /Applications/SWIProlog.app/Contents/swipl/library/win_menu.pl:205: Initialization goal raised exception:
>
> ERROR: file_base_name/2: Cannot represent due to `encoding' (Cannot represent char U0395 using current locale encoding)

I am using Mojave.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

I created a shell script in the user startup folder of the application, which executes the following two lines:

```
#! /bin/sh 
/bin/launchctl setenv LANG ja_JP.UTF-8
```

Obviously, `ja_JP.UTF-8` should be replaced with the appropriate locale for others.

Answer (score -1):

If you try `pwd.`, and the answer is `% //`, then you should not use the IDE of SWI-prolog. Instead, you could open it in the terminal with `SWI-prolog`.